# How do I create a a drop down box which echos a mysql record? PHP, SQL

Tags: php, sql, record

I am creating a website and need some assistance on how to create something similar to this:

https://matchstat.com/tennis/head-to-head

(the user can basically select any 2 players and compare their wins).

However, instead of typing into the search box, I will instead be using a drop down box, any ideas on how this can be achieved?

So far, I have set up my database and connected using the SQL, PHP.

A quick illustration of my form:

[select player] //this will be a drop down/options box

Forename: // the content of these fields will depend on what player the user has selected from the drop down / options box above
Surname:
Nationality:
DOB:
Height:
Weight:

Any advice would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the SQL query results stored an a 2d array (rows x columns), you can simply loop through the results of the array to print out the `<option>`s for the drop-down `<select>` box like so:

```
<?php

    $users = // SQL query result
    echo "<select>";

    foreach($users as $user) {
        $data = $user["forename"];
        echo "<option value='$data'>$data</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";

?>
```

---

By request, here is a more complex solution that creates a drop-down box *and* allows the data to be shown. This also uses jQuery (plain JS could also be used, but jQuery simplifies a lot):

```
<select id="dropdown">
<?php
    // this PHP is essentially the same as in the above example
    $users = [   // this is the test array I used. The SQL result should be in the same format for this to work.
        [
            "forename"=>"a_name",
            "dob"=>"never",
            "height"=>"too_tall",
            "weight"=>"too_heavy",
            "nationality"=>"martian"
        ],
        [
            "forename"=>"second_name",
            "dob"=>"always",
            "height"=>"too_short",
            "weight"=>"too_light",
            "nationality"=>"moon"
        ],
        [
            "forename"=>"third_name",
            "dob"=>"forever",
            "height"=>"300ft",
            "weight"=>"2000lb",
            "nationality"=>"Earth"
        ]
    ];
    $userDataArray = []; // multidimensional array
    $user_id = 0;
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $data = $user["forename"];
        echo "<option value='$user_id'>$data</option>";
        $user_id++;
        $userDataArray[] = [ "forename"=>$user["forename"], "dob"=>$user["dob"], "height"=>$user["height"], "weight"=>$user["weight"], "nationality"=>$user["nationality"] ];
        // index 0 = forename, 1 = DOB, 2 = height, 3 = weight, 4 = nationality
    }
?>
</select><br />
<span id="display"></span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jQuery library -->
<script>
    var users = [
        <?php  // translate PHP array to JS one
            foreach($userDataArray as $user) {
                echo "{ forename: '" . $user["forename"] . "', dob: '" . $user["dob"] . "', weight: '" . $user["weight"] . "', height: '" . $user["height"] . "', nationality: '" . $user["nationality"] . "'},";
            }
        ?>
    ];
    $("#dropdown").change(function() {
        var i = $("#dropdown").val();
        $("#display").html("Name: " + users[i].forename + "<br />DOB: " + users[i].dob + "<br />Weight: " + users[i].weight + "<br />Height: " + users[i].height + "<br />Nationality: " + users[i].nationality);
    });
</script>
```

Sorry this answer is so long and confusing. I'm not sure if there is any simpler way, especially when dealing with two different languages (and yes, you need both to deal with the server (database with PHP) and the client (dropdown with JS). I hope this helps!

See [the now correct output here](https://ideone.com/YUBXrO) at Ideone.

Comment: I will give this a go and get back. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Just make sure you substitute in the appropriate values for `$users` and `$forename`. I hope it helps!

Comment: Well, I managed to create a drop down box which shows the names of tennis players stored in the database. Now I need it so that when "Federer" is selected from the drop down box then his details such as DOB, Height, Weight, Nationality are displayed. Then when I select "Nadal" from the drop down box then his detail are displayed. How would I do that?

Comment: @AspiringIT That's a different idea altogether, and you're going to need JS/jQuery (a client-side language) to handle the changes of the drop-down box. But I can provide an example. Give me a few moments

Comment: the first part of your code returns an empty options box, help?

Comment: I just fixed it by adding mysqli_query, so your drop down works now

Comment: @AspiringIT Does it work now (if so, accept)? If not, what doesn't work?

Comment: $userDataArray = [][] shows the following error: Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in C:\wamp\www\test\new.php on line 5

Comment: @AspiringIT Try to remove the second pair of brackets. Looking back on it, I don't think it's necessary and is causing the error. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Have you tried to run the code yourself? $userDataArray is not doing anything. The drop down box does work though so that is excellent.

Comment: Its the $userDataArray that is not functioning I think, and the rest of the JS code doesnt do anything.

Comment: @AspiringIT I'm sorry, I have not tested it. I've been away and not on my home computer, just in my free time =P. But I will try on an online PHP compiler ASAP. Don't worry!

Comment: @AspiringIT I fixed (a LOT of errors on the code) and it works now. Sorry about that... if you have any questions just ask.

Comment: Hey, good new: I've got it partly working, BUT, I have a field called "Image" which stores the *path* of the image file and by using 

"    echo "<img src='$row[Path]' height='260' width='220'/>";       " I am able to call the image, however, this doesn't seem to work. 

Many thanks, you've been a great help.

Comment: I've got it working! The top part of your code REALLY helped, in the end I decided to hide/show <div> which are fed data via mysql query. The select option I couldn't have done without you, so thank you very much!

Comment: @AspiringIT I'm glad I helped! But apologies for taking so long for a working solution.